# Chemfig - how to make different colored bonds in a molecule

Tags: chemfig

I want to draw an ethanol molecule with a hydrogenbond to a water molecule.

I want the bond between them to be a dotted, red, line, but all the other bonds to be normal, yet I can't figure out how.

My code (so far) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O^{\delta^{-}}H^{\delta^{+}}--O^{\delta^{-}}(-H^{\delta^{+}})(-[6]H^{\delta^{+}})}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: `-[,2,,,thick, dotted, red]` instead of `--` should get you closer to the expected output.

Comment: @leandriis Exactly what I wanted! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

A slightly more complicated approach

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{center}
\chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-\charge{20:4pt=$^{\delta^{-}}$}{O}-[,0.5,,,draw=none]\charge{20:4pt=$^{\delta^{+}}$}{H}-[,1.5,,,draw=none,
    postaction={decorate},
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark = at position 0.22 with {\fill[red] circle[radius=1pt];},
        mark = at position 0.5 with {\fill[red] circle[radius=1pt];},
        mark = at position 1-0.22 with {\fill[red] circle[radius=1pt];}
    }
    ]\charge{20:4pt=$^{\delta^{-}}$}{O}(-[6]\charge{20:4pt=$^{\delta^{-}}$}{H})-\charge{20:4pt=$^{\delta^{+}}$}{H}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    dot diameter/.store in=\dot@diameter,
    dot diameter=1pt,
    dot spacing/.store in=\dot@spacing,
    dot spacing=5.5pt,
    dots/.style={
        line width=\dot@diameter,
        line cap=round,
        dash pattern=on 0pt off \dot@spacing
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O^{\delta^{-}}H^{\delta^{+}}-[,2,,,thick, dotted, red]\charge{20:4pt=$^{\delta^{-}}$}{O}(-[6]\charge{20:4pt=$^{\delta^{-}}$}{H})-\charge{20:4pt=$^{\delta^{+}}$}{H}}
\end{center}


\begin{center}
    \chemfig{H-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-C(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-O^{\delta^{-}}H^{\delta^{+}}-[,2,,,dots, red]\charge{20:4pt=$^{\delta^{-}}$}{O}(-[6]\charge{20:4pt=$^{\delta^{-}}$}{H})-\charge{20:4pt=$^{\delta^{+}}$}{H}}
\end{center}



\end{document}
```